# Como puedo convertir la URL de una imagen en base64 (IONIC 2)

Tags: ionic, cordova, ionic2

```
this.camera.getPicture({
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  quality: 100,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
}).then(imageData => {
  console.log('ESTA ES LA URI '+imageData);
  //como obtengo la imagen y la convierto en base64 ?
}, error => {
  this.error = JSON.stringify(error);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

En el [Framework Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/) de Ionic (*cordova-plugin-camera*):

```
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
 // If it's base64:
 let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});
```

Así pues, para crear una imagen en base64:

1. Insertas el string `'data:image/jpeg;base64,'` + el imageData

`let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;`

Solución:

```
console.log('data:image/png;base64,' + imageData);
```

---

**Edit**: 
- Hay que vigilar la codificación de la imagen:

En tu caso: `encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG`
Por lo tanto:

```
data:image/png;base64,
```

General:

```
data:image/[tipo de imagen];base64,
```

Donde:

[tipo de imagen] = jpeg, png, gif ...

Comment: Esa opcion solo funciona cuando destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL y este no es mi caso

Comment: Yo estoy usando destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI y esto solo devuelve la "Ruta de la imagen", como puedo obtener el archivo de dicha ruta y convertirlo en base64

Comment: Y si preguntas por que uso destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI es por que también necesito la ruta de la imagen. Saludos

Comment: Te entiendo. Prueba con esto: [http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/80/how-to-convert-a-image-from-the-device-to-base64-with-javascript-in-cordova](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/80/how-to-convert-a-image-from-the-device-to-base64-with-javascript-in-cordova)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el plugin de file http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/#readAsDataURL

Y utilizar el método this.file.readAsBinaryString(path, file);

este método te retorna un base 64

Answer (score -1):

```
this.camera.getPicture({
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, //convertir en base64
  quality: 100,
encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
}).then(imageData => {
  let image='data:image/png;base64,'+imageData;
  //sacando image en un img ya se mostrará 
}, error => {
  this.error = JSON.stringify(error);
});
```

Comment: Hola Monrae. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para que la respuesta sea de calidad has de añadir explicacion, no solo codigo. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo